# Change Column values in a dataframe in pandas using an external excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following

```
StructureID    Target Val   Measured Val
   'A'             2            1.8
   'A'             2            1.5
   'B'             4            4.6
   'C'             1            2.5
   'C'             1            2.3
   'C'             1            2.2
    .              .             .
    .              .             .
```

But the 'Target Val' column has the wrong target value. So, I need to replace the 'Target Val' column with the correct target value for the right 'StructureID'. I have another excel file where I have the 'Structure ID' and the correct 'Target Val'

```
   StructureID   Correct Target Val
        'A'             1.5
        'B'             3.0
        'C'             2.2
        'D'             1.0
         .               .
         .               .
```

My question - is there an easy way to match the structure ID with my first dataframe and populate the 'Target Val' col with the 'Correct Target Val' column from my excel file?

I have thought of making a dictionary to hold the correct target value for each structure id and do a for loop, but my approach is not efficient.

Comment: `df['StructureID'].map(map_df['StructureID'])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loop doesn't sound good... my solution is certainly not the most elegant one but should do the trick a lot faster.

1. Delete the column with the wrong values using .drop 
   `df1.drop(['Target Value'], axis=1)`
2. Merge the original dataframe `df1` with the one holding the correct values (`df2`) using the `StructureID` for joining
   `df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='StructureID', right_on='StructureID')`
   Check out the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for join types but from your example I think `'left'`seems like what you want if `df1` holds multiple rows per `StructureID` and `df`2 only holds one row per `StructureID`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


d1 = {'StructureID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'TargetVal': [2, 2, 4, 1], 'MeasuredVal': [1.8, 1.5, 4.6, 2.5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d2 = {'StructureID': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'TargetVal': [1.5, 3, 2.2]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

df1 = df1.drop(['TargetVal'], axis=1)

df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='StructureID', right_on='StructureID')
```

Comment: I tried your approach and it says "check for duplicates". Not sure how to merge while I have duplicate entries of structure ID on left dataframe. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: Can't try this now but I think duplicates in the left table should not be an issue with a left join. Sure you have no duplicates in the right table?

Comment: thanks it worked! I had an error in my column name.